# Different firestore behavior in prod build and local serve

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I am encountering an issue upon trying to retrieve values from my firestore collection.

In short, everything is going well in dev and test builds but as soon as I build my app for prod and run it on the server it behaves differently. The case is the following:

I am retrieving document as such in DEV

```js
// set the docRef
    const docRef = this.fire.collection('projects').doc(projectName);
    // get the snapshot
    docRef.ref.get()
    .then(doc => {
      // assign the variables
      doc.ref.onSnapshot(docu => {
        this.name = docu.data().name;
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

... and it works fine. In PRD this code breaks and returns:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I would like to be able to read my data consistently accross all build, what am I doing wrong? Do I have to assign my data first to an object/array?

Comment: `docu.data().name` is undefined.  What do you expect `name` to be instead?

Comment: Are you using the same database for your production app?

Comment: It should return a string value such as `Tripduc`

Comment: And yes @MichaelSorensen I am

Comment: I highly suggest checking your angular environment config settings. Firestore and firebase auth should perform the same provided the same arguments.

Comment: btw @MichaelSorensen, I am also performing some write actions that are working perfectly fine

Comment: Why do you expect that specific string?  Help us understand what data you're trying to query.  We can't see your database.  We don't even know if the document exists.